# Complicated Maven Dependency for Demonstration

Tags: maven

I have to perform a demonstration on the benefits of Maven. I am trying to find a complicated dependency with multiple levels of transitive dependencies to really show the power of the dependency management aspect of the tool.

The dependency should be in the Maven central repository as I want to keep the demonstration as simple as possible.

Can anybody suggest a suitable one? (The more complicated the better.)

Answer (score 1):

`hibernate-core` seems quite complicated:

```
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.0.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.15.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.1.Final:compile
```

Comment: Although hibernate did have quite a few dependencies, I was unable to resolve all the dependencies from the Maven central repository. I thought this made the demo a little more complicated so I ended up using `hadoop-core`. Thanks for your input though, I up-voted anyway as it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>it.unitn.margonar</groupId>

<artifactId>SpringMavenJPA</artifactId>

<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>

<dependency>

<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>

<artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>

<version>4.1.8.Final</version>

</dependency>

<dependency>

<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>

<artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>

<version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>

</dependency>

<dependency>

<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>

<artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>

<version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>

</dependency>

<dependency>

<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>

<artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>

<version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>

</dependency>

<dependency>

<groupId>postgresql</groupId>

<artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>

<version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>

</dependency>

<dependency>

<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>

<artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>

<version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>

</dependency>

<dependency>

<groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>

<artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>

<version>20030825.184428</version>

</dependency>

<dependency>

<groupId>commons-pool</groupId>

<artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>

<version>20030825.183949</version>

</dependency>

<dependency>

<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>

<artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>

<version>4.1.8.Final</version>

</dependency>

</dependencies>

</project>
```